# What fits the antenna mount point on a 10Zig 4448 thin client?

Tags: wireless-networking

Does anybody know the name (if it has one) of the type of antenna mounting point on a 10ZiG 4448 thin client?  Or the type of antenna/socket that would fit it?

[image: Image of part in question, indicated by green arrow]

I can't find any information on the 10ZiG web site (their docs only passingly mention "optional external antenna"), and I haven't been able to find an antenna or socket that looks like it would fit.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a slot for a [Kensington lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kensington_Security_Slot). An antenna connector would be a small, round, often gold-plated, threaded coax connector, maybe 4 mm in diameter.

Comment: Or maybe it's where the metal would have been punched out to fit the connector.

Comment: Perhaps ask at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/, if you get no answer here.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It does look a lot like a hole for a Kensington lock, but there is a Kensington hole located lower down on the same face and although similar, it isn't quite the same.  It could be intended to be punched out, but I suspect not as there is a minipci-e slot inside for future upgrade (e.g. a wireless card).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, Thank you, I will do that.

Comment: @confusedllama In that case, it is a punch-out for an RF connector, and you can see the sort of connector on the photo of the [6000q Series Thin Client](https://www.10zig.com/thin_clients). If you wanted to convert the 4448 to Wi-Fi, bear in mind that apart from a wireless card it *might* need more components on the PCB for things such as power for the card. Would it work with a USB Wi-Fi adapter?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, Thank you for your help (and for placing the image inline, I appreciate that).  Yes, I think USB WiFi might be the way to go (or wired Ethernet, of course), I just wondered whether it might have been a standard hole that somebody might be able to identify by sight.  Looks like it might be proprietary though, or at least quite obscure.  Since posting, I have the following extra information from 10ZiG:  The Wi-Fi card part number is "9020" and the wiring harness part number is "90xxHE".  Sadly no web site or data beyond that though, next step is to email sales with those numbers.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I've just realised that when you said "punch-out", you meant "a hole to accept a socket", not "a location to be further punched out prior to fitting an antenna/socket".  I didn't read it as "a hole to accept a socket" because I knew that was what it was, so I thought you must be suggesting the other thing.  That's why I said "It could be intended to be punched out but...". I understand now and yes, I agree, it is that, I just wanted to know what (if anything standard) will fit in it!

Comment: @confusedllama I did indeed mean "a location to be further punched out prior to fitting an antenna/socket". If you look up panel-mount SMA socket, you'll see the sort of thing that would be fitted in the hole. You can get them with a flat section to prevent rotation (I couldn't find a photo of one from a quick search).

Comment: @AndrewMorton, yes, that makes a lot of sense if 10ZiGs intention wasn't after-market upgrades but rather just an option when purchasing new, direct from 10ZiG.  Perhaps the slot is just to accommodate the punch tool.  That would also explain why I wasn't able to find any hint of the antenna/card for sale anywhere.  USB WiFi it is, then (unless I decide to get creative with a drill!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rectangular slot is to accommodate the end of a screwdriver!  The screwdriver can then be used to entirely remove that piece (which is just a blanking plate).

Beneath the blanking plate is a larger round hole able to accommodate a standard SMA (and possibly others) antenna socket.

For anybody wondering; There isn't any onboard WiFi but there is a Mini PCI Express slot inside which can be used for for a WiFi card.

Thank you @AndrewMorton, you were right about the likelihood of there needing to be a bigger, standard opening and prompted me to ask the correct question of 10ZiG, resulting in them sending me installation instructions which revealed the purpose of the slot!